# How to get the public path in Perl Dancer

Tags: path, document-root, dancer

Probably a silly question, but how do I get the path to the `/public` folder in Dancer?

I want to store/read csv files under the public folder, but don't know if Dancer offers any convenience methods to get the base path to the public folder.

The error I get when trying to create a file by saying:

```
open(FILE, ">>", "myapp/public/file.csv") or die "$!";
```

is:

```
No such file or directory in /ur/share/perl5/Dancer/Handler.pm l. 98
```

I'm not sure why it's going to Handler.pm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer is, don't do it that way...for two reasons:

1. You're potentially opening up a security issue. What if somehow a hacker figures out a way to write to your environment files, change your passwords, etc.?
2. You really want your /public files to be static, for version control, portability, etc.

That being said, if you really still want to do this, the public dir lives in config->{public}:

```
print "Public dir:".config->{public}."\n";
```

Source:
http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/Dancer-1.3110/lib/Dancer/Config.pm#public_%28directory%29

Comment: Are you saying it's a concern to put these files under public folder? I'm not sure then where to put such files (CSV data files)? Would it be a good idea to put them under bin? I don't think lib would be a good place for it as that has all my modules. Or should I just create my own folder?

Comment: If the CSV data files contain specific content that you'd like to serve, I would just create route(s) for them... GET '/file/somefile' for one specific file, or if many different files then GET '/file/:filename' and then fetch param('filename'), clean it up to avoid any hack attempts.  And yes if you want to store non-static files somewhere I would create my own separate folder (under myapp) and if you're using version control set it to ignore that folder (along with /logs, etc.).